# K Nearest neighbour vector matching without replacement (in R)

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

My question is very similar to what was asked in [Nearest neighbour vector matching without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081622/nearest-neighbour-vector-matching-without-replacement)

The only difference is: instead of finding the nearest neighbor for the query set, I'm looking for the nearest `k` neighbors of the query set in the subject.

```
query <- c(5,6)
subject <- c(1,2,4,7,8,9)
k <- 2
```

In this case, the desired output would be `c(2,4,7,8)`, not `c(4,7,4,7)`
I was wondering if there is an R function that gives this type of output?

Comment: How do you define the distance?

Comment: Euclidean distance.

Comment: why `c(2,4,7,8)` is closer neighbours than `c(4,7,4,7)`?

Comment: `c(4,7,4,7)` is closer, but the idea is "without replacement", so 4 and 7 shouldn't be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the thing you are after

```
> w <- embed(subject, k * length(query))[, (k * length(query)):1]

> w[which.min(colSums(abs(t(w) - rep(query, each = k)))), ]
[1] 2 4 7 8
```